# how to make lower case and delete the original column in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a very big data test. contain text. I wanted to make it all lower case I did this:

`df1=df.select("*", lower(col('name')))`

but it makes a new column called lower(name). I don't want to keep the previous column. So I deleted by this:

`df2=df1.drop(*'title_split')`

But it takes a lot to delete it. how I can make it faster? can I make it lower case and don't keep the previous one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `withColumn` to replace the old column:

```
df1 = df.withColumn('name2', lower(col('name'))).drop('name')
```

Comment: shouldn't I drop name2? I wanna keep the lower case

Comment: 'name2' is the lower case column, why do you want to drop it?

Comment: AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`name`' given input columns: [originaltitle, riginaltitle];;

Comment: you don't have a column called name. Which column do you want to convert to lower case?

Comment: `Originaltitles = Originaltitles.withColumn('originaltitle', lower(col('name'))).drop('name')`

Comment: I wanna do on originaltitle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227152/discussion-between-mck-and-nagh).